# How can I restore my party in the middle of an area I can't leave?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

On more than one occasion I have found my party right before a boss fight, at the heart of a fast-travel-denied area, and sometimes I can't even leave the place e.g.

> Inside the Astral Prism.

Without knowledge of that, I'm often not in great shape to tackle the fight. I've only succeeded by cheesing or luckily finding an Angelic Slumber potion.

Is there a way to fully restore the party in those situations (assuming I don't have the right spells and consumables), or do I need to load an older save file?

Comment: A level up will fully heal a party member

Comment: @Neon1024 No, it won't.

Comment: I guess short/long rests are no solution or blocked cause you don't mention them?

Comment: @Joachim It does for me, but I am in Story mode :)

Comment: @Neon1024 Ah, that makes sense! :)

Answer (score 1):

With restore, I'll assume you refer to both spell slots and hit points. Not all of the tips below directly address your problem, but might help you stay more prepared in the future.

- The only thing you didn't mention that could help you in this current situation, is to **use your Short Rests wisely** (see the uppermost icon in the image below).
  Apart from a full rest, you can at least regain half of your health pools with a short rest, and Warlocks will regain their abilities.

  [image: Resting options in Baldur's Gate 3]
  <sup>[source](https://primagames.com/tips/how-to-rest-in-baldurs-gate-3-bg3)</sup>
- I always take all **health potions** along: I never sell them, always take them from characters I leave behind in my camp, and prioritize their creation with my alchemical ingredients.
  Towards the end of Act II I even decided to buy any healing potions I come across, as well. I have more money than I know what to do with, so that seems like a no-brainer (an appropriate term for this game).
  And I tend not to use these potions unless I have to—that is, as long as Shadowheart has healing spells, I'll use those, and to make the most of it I temporarily equip her with any items that give a bonus prior to the healing ritual (Periapt of Wound Closure/Ring of Salving/Wapira’s Crown).
- Saying that, it's always good to **have a cleric or druid in your party** for exactly that purpose (which is more of a general D&D rule).

  - That also means (and I mention this for the sake of being thorough) it's not very wise to have a party consisting only of magic wielders. If they run out of spells, they're sitting ducks.
- Moreover, just **rest often**. There are enough Camp Supplies around. Long rests can only cause problems under specific circumstances, and these are usually obvious and/or pointed out (if a character is choking to death in a room filled with gas, and you're the only ones around to save them, it makes sense not to wait too long).
- **Use magic scrolls and potions** you pick up along the way. Don't be stingy with them (well, not when they can save your life). If your mage ran out of spell slots, they can still burn through an arsenal of scrolls. Let your rogues/rangers/fighters dip their arrows or blades in poisons, and see how much more damage you can do in a single turn.
- Make note *and use* of the **weaknesses of your enemies**. Right-click them or their icons, and check what they will easily withstand or really cannot tolerate, then adjust the use of those scrolls and potions accordingly.

I hope this helps you a little, at least.

Comment: Paladins make quite decent healers too - it's quite possible to have a party with Minthara as the only healer (but Shadowheart/Halsin/Jaheira are the best ones obviously). In my current playthrough, I like to use fighter main + Minthara + Gale + Minsc. Healing is ok, dps is great and defence is through the roof, so not as much healing is needed (although both main and Minsc have tank builds).

Answer (score 1):

- I strongly recommend to keep *Potions of Angelic Reprieve* and  *Potions of Angelic Slumber* around for these very occasions (no camping areas). These potions can even be used in combat, if you can only find some spot to nap in the middle of it. The latter is craftable.

  (And the item description is quite amusing: "One of the few ways for elves to experience sleep. Other methods include taking narcotics and being hit very hard with a chair.")
- Clerics eventually get a kind of epic feat *Divine Intervention* where they can ask for a divine favour to their deity just once during the whole play-through. I think it depends a bit on the character and type of deity, but among the things you can (probably?) ask for is:

  > Resurrect fallen companions with half their hit points, and restore all nearby allies as if they had Long Rested.

  You might think that saving it for the final battle (in case you plan to bring a cleric to it) is wise, but I'd say there are a couple of even harder boss fights before then. So don't hesitate to use up this feat if you are really struggling with one particular boss fight.